# Cscope egrep speedup

Tags: cscope

I use cscope in vim to search for stuff in a large codebase. I find the `"cs f e"` option too slow. Anyway tips speed it up. I build my cscope database using `cscope -bq`

Comment: How large is your codebase? How slow is "too slow"? What platform are you using? Is your source code on a local filesystem or a network filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

cscope will not speedup grep and egrep with database (almost). This is because cscope will not build any inverted index for any possible substring nor will use some regex-speedup technique with some type of precomputed index. The only speedup is that cscope will run grep/egrep function only on source files and this is speedup only when comparing with `grep regex -r .` (which will check binaries .obj, .exe too).

Egrep function can't use cscope database.

So, move your code to local fs (from network fs), install more memory, disable collating via env LC_ALL=C or LC_ALL=POSIX, disable atime on your fs.

You can also move your fs to SSD or RAMDISK.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Somehow opengrok is much faster for egrep like searches. The code is a few million lines of code (just guessing here, basically I want to say reasonably large).